# Adding "read more" / "read less" button to long product descriptions in Woocommerce: how do I hide the button when it's not needed?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woomcommerce store where the products have varying description lengths.  I have added a "read more"/"read less" button that works on the longer product descriptions.  However on the shorter descriptions, the button is visible but obviously doesn't do anything as there's nothing to toggle.  How can I hide the button on the short descriptions?

This is the PHP for the new templates/single-product/short-description.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if ( ! $short_description ){
    return;
}
?>

<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description" itemprop="description-container">

    <div class="product-description rte" itemprop="description">

<?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    </div>

    <a class="readmore" href="#"><?php echo 'Read more...'?></a>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.readmore').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var description = document.querySelector('.product-description');
        console.log(description.style.height)
        if (description.style.height === ''){
          description.style.height = 'auto';
        } else if (description.style.height === 'auto'){
          description.style.height = '';
        }
        else{
          description.style.height = '92px';
        }

        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less...' ? 'Read more...' : 'Read less...');
    });
});
```

So right now the read more/read less toggle works perfectly, but I'd really like to know how to hide it on short descriptions where it's not necessary!  Thank you!

Comment: Test the content for a specific length and don't display the button if the content is less than that length

Comment: I banging my head right now, I can't believe I forgot to do that.  I added ````<?php 
 if (strlen($short_description) > 250){
 ?>
 <a class="readmore" href="#">
  <?php echo 'Read more...';
  
 }?></a>
```` it works now

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include code to check for length. The correct PHP in the template should be

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if ( ! $short_description ){
    return;
}
?>

<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description" itemprop="description-container">

    <div class="product-description rte" itemprop="description">

<?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    if (strlen($short_description) > 250){
    ?>
    <a class="readmore" href="#">
        <?php echo 'Read more...';

    }?></a>

</div>
```

It works now, only shows the readmore when the description is greater than 250 characters.